# Self-growing array java

Tags: java, arrays

The question is to implement the three methods `get(int index)`, `set(intindex)`, and the constructor `SelfGrowingArray()` in order to produce the sentences shown in the main method. While it compiles, I get an `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException`, specifically, this error:

```
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, You don't know you're beautiful]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, You don't know you're beautiful, null, null, null, null, null, null, What doesn't kill you makes you stronger.]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -14
```

Here is my code, please help:

```
public class SelfGrowingArray {

private Object[] data;

public SelfGrowingArray()
{
    data = new Object[0];
}

public void set(int index, Object value)
{
    if (index >= data.length) {
        Object[] newArray = new Object[index + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        newArray[i] = data[i];
        }
        data = newArray;
        }
        data[index] = value;    
}

public Object get(int index)
{
    if (index >= data.length)
    return null;
    return data[index];
}

public String toString()
{
    if (data == null)
    {
        return "null";
    }

    int iMax = data.length - 1;
    if (iMax == -1)
    {
        return "[]";
    }

    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append('[');
    for (int i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        b.append(data[i]);
        if (i == iMax)
        {
            return b.append(']').toString();
        }
        b.append(", ");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SelfGrowingArray myList = new SelfGrowingArray();
    myList.set(14, "You don't know you're beautiful");
    System.out.println(myList);

    myList.set(21, "What doesn't kill you makes you stronger.");
    System.out.println(myList);

    System.out.println("myList.get(-14) " + myList.get(-14));
    System.out.println("myList.get(14) " + myList.get(14));
    System.out.println("myList.get(15) " + myList.get(15));
    System.out.println("myList.get(31) " + myList.get(31));
    System.out.println("myList.get(32) " + myList.get(32));

}
}
```

Comment: have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: Your `toString()` method is hideous!

Comment: To John3136, to be fair that was given to us already, I specified in the question which methods I needed to implement myself.

Comment: Wow, I would seriously question the competence of someone who gave you that `toString` method.

Comment: My professor haha, he's been known to make things overly complicated to test our skills

Comment: @user2259570 You do realise that `toString()` doesn't actually compile? - not all paths have a return statement.

Comment: @user2259570 When you wrote `myList.get(-14)` what were you expecting to happen?  If that was "given to you", then what does the specification say should happen for an invalid index?

Comment: I didn't write myList.get(-14), that was given to us already by our professor, we had to implement the methods I stated in the question

Comment: This leads to 2 questions: 1) Does a `SelfGrowingArray` support negative indexes?; and 2) What should `get()` do if you attempt to retrieve an element that you have not set -- return null or throw an exception?  The answers to these questions will tell you what you need to do in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -14

The problem is here:

```
myList.get(-14)
```

You can't access to an index lesser than 0. Modify your `get` method to support negative indexes:

```
public Object get(int index) {
    if (index >= data.length || index < 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return data[index];
}
```

Comment: How does this "support negative indexes"?  Maybe he comes from a different language where negative indexes count from the end of an array?

Comment: @JimGarrison the *support for negative indexes* means to return `null` when getting a negative index instead of just letting the program blowing out.

Comment: Where is that documented?  Why does it have to be that way?

Comment: @JimGarrison if you don't like it, please post an answer and show that we're wrong :).

Comment: You have made a possibly incorrect assumption about what is desired. Please see my question to the OP on the original post.

Comment: @JimGarrison so it would be better to return the element at index 0 or to let the Exception propagate? I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

As it says you have an exception while trying to retrieve value from index [-14] in your get method you should check if the index value is not below zero.

```
public Object get(int index)
{
   if (index >= data.length || index < 0)
     return null;
   return data[index];
}
```

Comment: @JimGarrison there's no problem with this code (none that I can find)